# What type of SQL queries must have data on 1 server (can not be distributed to different servers)?

Tags: sql, redis, sharding

I am evaluating e.g. RediSQL which must hold all data on 1 server in order to execute SQL query. It basically can read data only from that one same server (can not aggregate data from a cluster).

Thinking now on a high level - which use cases / types of queries this will support? (e.g. ST.Dev.... or some heavy mathematical functions) which Must hold all data on 1 server?

Answer (score 0):

So Basically You do not want to share your Sql server to your network? There is no query like this type of validation but you can check it out from this link
How to disable Network Sharing on sql server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This is a question more on can 1 single instance VS cluster. In case of RediSQL - we can NOT use cluster so want to evaluate what type of queries can benefit that more than running SQL on a cluster..